# How to delay page transition in NextJs

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, frontend

I am trying to protect my private pages using `HOC withAuth`. Protection works fine but i dont want users to see loading for second while access token is being retrieved from `local storage`. And if i were to just return `null` after redirecting i get error that says `received div without enclosing div` (or something like that). Is there any way to delay route transition ? My HOC is

```
export function withAuth<T extends TWithAuth = TWithAuth>(
   WrappedComponent: React.ComponentType<T>,
   ): React.ComponentType<T> {
const InnerComponent = (props: T) => {
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const router = useRouter();
    useEffect(() => {
        const accessToken = TokenService.getAccessToken();

        if (!accessToken) {
            router.replace('/auth/login');
        } else {
            setLoading(false);
        }
    }, []);
    return loading ? <div>loading</div> : <WrappedComponent {...props} />;
};

InnerComponent.displayName = `withAuth(${WrappedComponent.displayName || WrappedComponent.name}`;

return InnerComponent;
```

}

Comment: That's not preventable if the authentication happens client-side. The only way to avoid that behaviour is to do the check server-side, but that would modify your approach quite a bit.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use getServerSideProps on your private pages and wrap it inside your component that's handling the logic and would return a

```
{ redirect: { destination: "/auth/login" } }
```

if there is no accessToken